# Subform multi criteria query not working?

Tags: vba, criteria, ms-access-2016, subform

I have a **form** `frmTagSearch` which contains a **textbox** `txtSearchTerm` a **search button** `btnSearch` and a **subform** `subfrmTagQuery`.

The subform was created using the wizard from a pre-existing query `qryStakeholderTag`. The query itself has no criteria.

The aim is to use the value of `txtSearchTerm` to get the subform to show those records in `qryStakeholderTag` where the `txtSearchTerm` value appears in any of the Organisation, Role or Comms Notes fields.

The code I have for this is below (the Debug line is to check I have the right quote marks). In most cases this returns no records, although with one search term the query does return 3 records - not the 'right' number, but at least it appears to be doing something.

Can anyone advise what I'm getting wrong here? I pretty much copied the code from another forum where it was marked as an answer to a similar-sounding problem.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

If Me.txtSearchTerm = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Me.subfrmTagQuery.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM qryStakeholderTag WHERE Organisation LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearchTerm & _
    "*' OR qryStakeholderTag.Role LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearchTerm & _
    "*' OR qryStakeholderTag.[Comms Notes] LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearchTerm & "*'"
Debug.Print Me.subfrmTagQuery.Form.RecordSource
Me.subfrmTagQuery.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: I should maybe add that the subfrmTagQuery has as its Record Source qryStakeholderTag, but I am thinking this should be overwritten by the code in any case each time btnSearch is clicked...?

Comment: @HansUp The line shows the Record Source string just how I would expect to see it, but as it's just a string it could show anything really.

Answer (score 0):

I had the eureka/d'oh moment last night. The query on which the subform is based has two source tables, `Stakeholders` and `Organisations`. `Stakeholders` has a lookup field that links to `Organisations!Organisation`; I had pulled the `Stakeholders!Organisation` field into the query, so the RecordSource was trying to find a search string in a field that only included lookup ID indeces. My defence, apart from being a bit slow, is that of course the query displays the expected text.

Amending the query design to include the `Organisations!Organisation` field has fixed the issue. :)